# cURL Button Click POST Issue

Tags: unix, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to perform a button click via cURL and I am having an issue possibly due to java script on click.  The HTML source code is:

```
<input id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_1bb6dc86_55ab_4ea9_a4db_4747922a8202_ctl00_RequestOption_0" class="radio" type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_1bb6dc86_55ab_4ea9_a4db_4747922a8202$ctl00$RequestOption">
<label for="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_1bb6dc86_55ab_4ea9_a4db_4747922a8202_ctl00_RequestOption_0">    View Summary Data Online</label>
```

i send the command this way but it still does not perform that click event:

```
curl -d "RequestOption_0=1" https://xxx.xxxxx.com/customer-service/rates-pricing/customer-choice/Pages/usage-data.aspx > test20121812.txt
```

How is the POST supposed to be?  Please note that I am using cURL for Windows.  Thank you!

Comment: please post your complete code.a link to the page would also be helpful.